# Why doesn't TreeSet accept duplicate custom objects even though equals and hashcode are not overridden in custom object?

Tags: collections, set, hashset, treeset

```
public class Coll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Silver> set = new TreeSet<Silver>(new Gold());
        Silver silver = new Silver("1");
        Silver silver2 = new Silver("1");
        set.add(silver);
        System.out.println(set.add(silver2));
        System.out.println(set.size()); 
    }
}

class Silver {
    private String qty;

    public Silver(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}

class Gold implements Comparator<Silver> {
    public int compare(Silver obj1, Silver obj2) {
        return obj1.getQty().compareTo(obj2.getQty());
    }
}
```

Comment: proper question is this i have created 2 custom objects silver and silver2 in this class class(silver)) i have not overridden both equals() and hashcode(), i'm inserting these objects in treeset,since i have not overrode hashcode and equals method it should accept both the objects, but it is accepting only one object. what is the reason behind it?